# Can I change the position of label in MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI for react,I want to change the place of label in text fields and bring it to the right, but because it has motion it doesn't look good how can I change that?
[image]
I want it to be like this but the white part doesn't move.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for MUI v5

1. Add `dir` attribute to your `body` tag or any container where you want to apply rtl direction styles.
2. Set the direction

```
const theme = createTheme({
  direction: 'rtl',
});
```

3. Install [stylis-plugin-rtl](https://github.com/styled-components/stylis-plugin-rtl)
4. Load the `rtl` plugin and wrap it around your components

```
const cacheRtl = createCache({
  key: 'muirtl',
  stylisPlugins: [rtlPlugin],
});

function RTL(props) {
  return <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>{props.children}</CacheProvider>;
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtl-textfield-mui-moebp)

[Source MUI v5](https://mui.com/guides/right-to-left/)

[Source MaterialUI v4](https://v4.mui.com/guides/right-to-left/)